# Asymptotic behaviour of $\int_0^1 g(x)\exp(-nx)dx$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, asymptotics

Let $g:(0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}_+$ be an invertible monotonically non-increasing function that integrates to $1$ and has $g(1)=0$, $g(0)=\infty$; eg. $g(x)=x^{-1/2}-1$ or $g(x)=\ln(1/x)$. I believe it is the case that:
$$
\int_0^1 g(x)\exp(-nx)dx=\Theta(g(1/n)/n)
$$
but I'm not having any luck showing this in general. I'd also like to know if there are particular tools that work well for computing integrals of this form generally.

Comment: The statement is true for your two examples.  The case $g(x) = x^{-1/2}-1$ follows from [Watson's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson's_lemma), while the case $g(x) = \ln(1/x)$ follows from a result of Erdélyi that I summarize in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1223177/5531).  There are more straightforward ways to verify it in those cases, but these tools are good to know.

Comment: What does $\Theta$ stand for? This integral can be evaluated by iterating integration by parts obtaining a meaningful asymptotic series in $1/n$.

Comment: $\Theta$ is big theta notation, meaning in this case the integral is bounded asymptotically above and below by $g(1/n)/n$. Naive integration by parts doesn't work here because $g(0)=\infty$.

@AntonioVargas, thanks; I hadn't heard of either of those techniques before.